# jenkins job is hangs, and runs continuously

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver, testng

My job in jenkins runs 2 times a day. Last few days it is Started after some time showing estimated remaining time:N/A. And blue color seems change to red color and still running. I don't why it is showing like this.

After some time i need to abort and start the run again, again same issue..

It is running hours and hours but no out put.

How to i rectify this, nothing wrong in my script. I executed 10's times in Eclipse, then only i pushed into SVN. Before builds also same scripts passed, but now the job is not responding, it is hanging(means estimated time:N/A and colour in Red, in build history).

This problem occurs from last few builds.
Any one can explain the problems why this behave like this?

Comment: What does it show on the job console ?

Comment: The environment the job is run under by Jenkins is probably not the same as that you used when coding in eclipse.  Check your PATHs and Environment Variables for differences and make sure you make them agree.  (BTW, without note of OS you are using, I can't give much more.)

Comment: After 4 hrs, i was aborted the job. So Build Aborted. Not looking for any TestNG results is the console out put. Same job was run successfully in 25 - 35 mins. But now it is still runing after 4 hrs also so i aborted.

Comment: Again, what does it show on the job console? Did the tests even begin? Or the job was hanging even before updating SVN repository? There is very little info to tell what could probably go wrong.